# Ich mache in...

Tags: phrase, usage, etymology

Woher genau kommt denn eigentlich der Ausdruck *"Ich mache in [Immobilien]"*? Das klingt für mich lediglich unhygienisch. Wo/wann wird dieser Ausdruck einem *"Ich bin [Makler]"* oder *"Ich arbeite als [Makler]"* bevorzugt?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Mal wieder aus dem Grimm:

> 9) machen *in kaufmännischer rede, ein geschäft machen, handel treiben:* er macht in strumpfwaaren; in wein machen; auf diesem platze wird in spirituosen, auf jenem in getreide gemacht; *übertragen hört man auch:* er macht jetzt in frömmigkeit; er macht stark in patriotismus. wir haben schlecht gemacht, *sagt der walfischfänger vom schlechten fange. Brem. sonntagsbl.* 1854 23.

Es kommt also aus der kaufmännischen Rede und ist auch keine Erfindung des letzten Jahrhunderts. Heutzutage hat es aber tatsächlich eher umgangssprachliche Konnotation; mir ist nicht bekannt, ob die Formulierung in der kaufmännischen Sprache heute immer noch Usus ist.

Answer (score 3):

Wie aus [OregonGhosts Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/765/ich-mache-in/770#770) klar wird, stammt der Ausdruck aus der kaufmännischen Rede und ist eine mehrere Jahrhunderte alte Formulierung.

Ich vermutete ursprünglich, dass er ein Anglizismus ist, der aus der englischen Wendung *to make money in [the stock market]* abgeleitet und verkürzt wurde.

Was meine subjektive Bewertung des Ausdrucks angeht empfinde die Verwendung in heutiger Zeit arrogant und wichtigtuerisch.

Comment: Für mich klingt es mehr umgangssprachlich als arrogant oder wichtigtuerisch.